# Android Java - Shared Preferences Editor Issue

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'am trying to permentantly store values from 3 differenct strings into Shared Preferences. The strings definately contain the values as i have tested them by setting the strings in a textView.

```
public class verified extends Activity{

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    TextView textView100;
     String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPreferences" ;

        String NString;
        String MString;
        String EAString;

           public static final String MVerified = "";
           public static final String NVerified = "";
           public static final String EAVerified = "";



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verified);

  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         NString = bundle.getString("NString");
     MString = bundle.getString("MString");
     EAString = bundle.getString("EAString");

      textView100 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView100);

    textView100.setText(MString + " , " + NString + " , " + EAString);


        Button VCompleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.VCompleteButton);

        VCompleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
           public void onClick(View view) 
           {    



             Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
             editor.putString(MVerified, MString);
             editor.putString(NVerified, NString);
             editor.putString(EAVerified, EAString);
             editor.commit(); 


           }



           });


 }



}
```

However the issue now is that the EAString is storing its value in all three of the. sharedPreferences.
When I execute this on the main activity. It shows me the EAStrin 3 times.

```
textView2.setText((sharedpreferences.getString(MobileVerified, "")) + " , "+ (sharedpreferences.getString(NameVerified, "")) +  " , "+ (sharedpreferences.getString(EmailAddressVerified, "")));
```

Comment: Why is MVerified Nverified EAverified all = "";
You need to give them a value and then on (sharedpreferences.getString(MobileVerified, ""))
make sure those strings match

Comment: The three keys - MVerified, NVerified and EAverified are all empty? Why is this. You need to have different keys to retrieve the different values. Else the value that was last inserted overrides the previous key with same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never initiate `sharedpreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
```

thats the reason why you get a NullPointerException here:

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
```

put something like this in your onCreate method before using SharedPreferences:

```
sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

that are your keys:

```
public static final String MVerified = "";
           public static final String NVerified = "";
           public static final String EAVerified = "";
```

each key is an empty String.
You have to define a key for each entry in your SharedPreferences:

```
public static final String MVerified = "key1";
           public static final String NVerified = "key2";
           public static final String EAVerified = "key3";
```

otherwise you overwrite each entry with the next one...

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;   is initiated on the second line of the code

Comment: no you declared it but you did not initiate it. Take a look in your stacktrace. I bet you have an error in the line of sharedpreferences.edit();

Comment: hu i have initialised the sharedpreferences now. please see revised code. Now the issue i have got is that for some reason EA String is being saved in all 3 of the Shared Preferences.look at the extra code above

Answer (score 0):

You have declared but not initiated SharedPreferences. Do this:

```
SharedReferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); // common instance that will be shared for this context
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if your not including the `@Override` annotation for your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` Method. Nor do you include this same annotation when overriding the `View`s `onClick(View v)` method.